# Swift - how to extract a byte array from AnyObject

Tags: swift

I have json data. Here's a snippet:

```
{"entries":[{"a":"153","b":"7","d":[0,0,4,-122,-1,0,0,-1,-64,64,-26,34,35,120]}
```

I have extracted the "entries" to create a [[String:AnyObjects]] and pass this to the function "entryFromJSONObject"

```
fileprivate func entryFromJSONObject(json: [String : AnyObject]) {
    let _id = json["a"] as? String,
    let cidA = json["b"] as? String,
    let dataArray = json["d"] as? Array<UInt8>
    // etc
}
```

This code successfully parses "id" and "cidA" but always fails to create the data array named dataArray.

I have searched extensively for how to cast/convert AnyObject to a UInt8 array but cannot find an answer that works. Via xcode 9.0 I have verified json["d"] is of type Swift.AnyObject? and the data is in memory.

How can I achieve what I wish to do? I'm using Swift 3.2. This code may have worked in a earlier version of Swift - either that or I had a fault in my testing!

Comment: Why `UInt8 ` where it have negative number?? Why not just use `[Int]`?

Comment: `json["d"]` is an array of `Int` (`[Int]`), not `UInt8`.

Comment: You can cast to array of Int8 and map them using `UInt8(bitPattern:)` initializer

Comment: Thanks to rmaddy and Tj3n. They are correct in that json["d"] is an array of Int. My confusion was due to the original data before being JSON serialised having an array of bytes. The JSON serialisation/deserialisation turned this into an array of Int. In my case I need an array of bytes, so I'll add code to convert my dataArray: [Int] to an array of bytes. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Don’t use AnyObject. You should use Swift native dictionary type [String:Any]. Don’t cast to [Int] cast to [Int8] that has the same amount of bytes as an array of UInt8. Why Any? because AnyObject can hold only classes not structures. Most Swift types are structures (String, Double, Int, Array, Dictionary, etc...). If you use AnyObject they will be bridged to their NS counterparts like NSString, NSNumber, NSArray and NSDictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast your byte values to Int8 and use UInt8(bitPattern:)  initializer to map it into bytes:

```
let jsonStr = """
{"entries":[{"a":"153","b":"7","d":[0,0,4,-122,-1,0,0,-1,-64,64,-26,34,35,120]}]}
"""
let jsonDict = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: Data(jsonStr.utf8)) as! [String : Any]

func entryFromJSONObject(json: [String : Any]) {
    if let dictionaries = json["entries"] as? [[String: Any]],
        let dict = dictionaries.first,
        let id = dict["a"] as? String,
        let cidA = dict["b"] as? String,
        let dataArray = dict["d"] as? Array<Int8>  {
        print(id)    // "153\n"
        print(cidA)  // "7\n"
        print(dataArray) // "[0, 0, 4, -122, -1, 0, 0, -1, -64, 64, -26, 34, 35, 120]\n"
        let bytes = dataArray.flatMap { UInt8(bitPattern: $0) }
        print(bytes)  // [0, 0, 4, 134, 255, 0, 0, 255, 192, 64, 230, 34, 35, 120]\n"
    }
}
```

---

If you are just passing the first dictionary from your entries array of dictionaries, you can do as follow:

```
let jsonDic = """
{"a":"153","b":"7","d":[0,0,4,-122,-1,0,0,-1,-64,64,-26,34,35,120]}
"""
let jsonDict = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: Data(jsonDic.utf8)) as! [String : Any]
func entryFromJSONObject(json: [String : Any]) {
        if let id = json["a"] as? String,
        let cidA = json["b"] as? String,
        let dataArray = json["d"] as? Array<Int8>  {
        print(id)    // "153\n"
        print(cidA)  // "7\n"
        print(dataArray) // "[0, 0, 4, -122, -1, 0, 0, -1, -64, 64, -26, 34, 35, 120]\n"
        let bytes = dataArray.flatMap { UInt8(bitPattern: $0) }
        print(bytes)  // [0, 0, 4, 134, 255, 0, 0, 255, 192, 64, 230, 34, 35, 120]\n"
    }
}

entryFromJSONObject(json: jsonDict)
```